# member? function in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am following Brian Harvey's SICP lectures from 2011 on the [UC Berkeley site](http://webcast.berkeley.edu/playlist#c,d,Computer_Science,EC3E89002AA9B9879E). He is using the [STk interpreter](http://kaolin.essi.fr/STk/) to teach the class and I am using racket with DrRacket to follow along. I am trying to define all of the functions he uses in the class that are not defined in racket (i.e. `word`, `butfirst`, `butlast`) for extra practice.

I have run into an issue trying to define `member?`. He is able to use it on lists and strings, doing things like

```
(member? 1 (list 1 2 3 4)) ;; works
(member? 'a '(a e i o u)) ;; works
(member? 7 17) ;; doesn't work
(member? #\e "Hello") ;; doesn't work
```

Here is my definition of `member?` for which the above do/don't work:

```
(define (member? u lst)
  (not (equal? (member u lst) #f)))
```

So this is working with a list, so the first two make sense that they are working. Is it even possible to create a function to mimic `member?` in STk? I was looking at the docs and it looks like strings, lists, non-negative integers and a bunch of other stuff are defined as `sequence` datatypes but I can't find a relevant sequence function.

Comment: You may also find the following library helpful: http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/dyoo/simply-scheme.plt/2/2/planet-docs/manual/index.html.  If I understand the situation right, Brian Harvey is pre-loading a few definitions from his Simply Scheme textbook.

Comment: While it won't help with the STk Scheme specific homework, but if you pursue problems from the book, you might want to look at Dr. Racket support for SICP at http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/.

Comment: @dyoo Yep, that is exactly what I am trying to replicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sequence-ormap` for this:

```
(define (member? item seq)
  (sequence-ormap (lambda (x)
                    (equal? item x))
                  seq))
```

To test:

```
> (member? 7 17)
#t
> (member? #\e "Hello")
#t
```

Comment: That `lambda (x)` function is basically like `seq.forEach(function (x) { });`, right?

Comment: `lambda` creates a function, but `lambda` itself is not a function. :-) But yes, it maps to the `function (x) ...` concept directly.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you know the Racket function `sequence-ormap` here is something to help with learning Scheme:

```
(define (member? test item sequence)
  (cond ((string? sequence) (member? test item (string->list sequence)))
        ((vector? sequence) (member? test item (vector->list sequence)))
        ;; ...
        ((list? sequence) 
         (let looking ((l sequence))
           (and (not (null? l))
                (or (test item (car l))
                    (looking (cdr l))))))
        (else 'not-a-sequence)))

(define (member?-using-test test)
  (lambda (item sequence) (member? test item sequence))

(define member-equal? (member?-using-test equal?))
```

Comment: Is this similar to what `sequence-ormap` is doing under the hood? In that it is using a conditional for the type of `sequence`? I'm trying to look at the [source](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/7041ea1d80342c48a4d426eb1fcaa9a96c1ebc92/collects/racket/private/sequence.rkt) but it looks like it's all abstracted out.

Comment: At some level 'sequence-ormap' must be branching on the different types: string?, vector?, etc.

Comment: @GoZoner Yes, but it does so using a much more "object-oriented" approach: sequence types simply implement a sequence interface. Doing this kind of branching inside your `member?` function isn't very OO at all. :-) The ramification of OO vs non-OO is that if you need to add a new sequence type, it's _much_ easier to do under the OO approach.

Comment: @theyshookhands The "all abstracted out" is exactly what object-oriented programming is all about, and it enables you to add new sequence types without having to change all the places that use sequences. :-)

Comment: Yeah, that is the reason I was asking. Defining a `member?` function in OO for all `sequence` datatypes makes sense. Doing it like this, however, by checking the sequence for all types, seems like an anti-pattern.

Comment: Well, since when are we talking about OO?  We are talking SICP and Scheme, right?  In Scheme, <list>, <vector>, <string> (with corresponding predicates list?, vector? and string?) are all disjoint types. See section 3.2, page 10 "Disjointness of Types" (in R7RS draft 8 and other Scheme reports).  There is no OO-like sequence? predicate in Scheme.  Of course, implementations can implement stuff as they see fit and add non-Scheme functions; but that is non-Scheme.

Comment: Furthermore, Scheme does not have OO built into the core; so, if you intend to layer OO on Scheme, then you will be conditionalizing off of the built-in types.  Fact.

Comment: I am biased towards OO when I say that is seems like an anti-pattern. But is OO not obviously the solution to this problem?

Comment: You are doing homework, or more generally studying, with a need to write a member? function.  Write it as you please.